# All of the Xposed framework zips I flashed gave me a bootloop. Why is that so?

Tags: root-access, nexus-4, 5.1-lollipop, xposed-framework

I have a Google Nexus 4 running stock 5.1.1. It's rooted. I'm aware that there is no official release of Xposed for SDK 22. I tried flashing more than two unofficial zips via TWRP. And all of them gave me a bootloop. Yes, I cleared the Dalvik cache. I badly want to get Xposed GEL settings.

Comment: What do you mean there's no offical release for SDK 22? What is this then? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I couldn't get it from the Xposed website. It isnt the final version, right?

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for Nexus 4 running stock and rooted Android 5.1.1:

1. Download the xposed-v79-sdk22-arm.zip from the official Xposed Framework [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) on XDA forum
2. Install that zip via recovery mode
3. Clear Dalvik/Cache